# Angular CDK Drag and drop with placeholders in one of the drop lists

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, angular-dragdrop, angulardraganddroplists

I am struggling with the following use case for Angular CDK Drag and Drop: I want the second drop list to be an array with empty elements when the component loads (because I want to have a number of placeholders there that can be replaced by the elements dragged from the first list).

I created a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-iiuhq?fontsize=14

I think the code is ok as idea (although for some reason I cannot get it to work in the sandbox). The only problem is that the dragging is super unnatural and choppy. I'd want the placeholder to remain visible until I dragged the element on top of it, then disappear beneath the dragged element. Now, it seems like the dragged element pushes the others left and right or up and down and then one of the placeholders disappears.

Maybe you guys have a better approach that I didn't think about.

Also, I know about the `*cdkDragPlaceholder` directive, but it was not obvious to me how I could use it in one of the drop lists and make the placeholders visible there always (so not only when the drag event starts).

Answer (score 0):

I used one cdkDropList per element for simular task: [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srg6e3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.ts)

Comment: I ended up doing that too in the end. Your example is not working, btw

Comment: Thanks for testing it) It works it just needs >1430px browser window . https://angular-srg6e3.stackblitz.io